# Python best practices to where do I have install Python and its modules

Tags: python, installation, module

I am newer coder (if I can call myself like that)

I am having certain problems when run my python code. As you can see in the following information looks like I have installed several versions of python or maybe the same version in different binders. It could be creating problems when I run my code.

Also, I have installed all modules or libraries in another binder.

What I really want to know is what which are the best practices or rules to have a very clean Python and its modules installation.

---

> C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Python Training>pip list  Package  Version
> -------- -------  asgiref  3.7.2  colorama 0.4.6  Django   5.0.2  numpy    1.26.4  pillow   10.2.0  pip      24.0  pyarrow  15.0.0
> pylance  0.9.18  sqlparse 0.4.4  tzdata   2024.1
> C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Python Training>where python
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe
> C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
> C:\Users\HP\OneDrive\Python Training>

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "Rules" on where to install python, it's all up to personal preference, but having multiple installations with different libraries added to them can cause issues. I suggest  deleting the installation with the lesser amount of libraries and adding all missing libraries to the larger installation.

Comment: Thank. Just one additional question before proceeding to uninstalling or deleting python. As you can see in the message, I have installed Python on OneDrive. So, there is no problem with this kind installation?